# Use swiper grid as navigation for gallery / thumbs gallery

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am working on a project to create a swiper thumbs gallery to display work instructions. I have this working fairly well but want to take it further.

Right now the user clicks through the thumb gallery or uses the navigation arrows to progress through the work instruction. If the user wants to get to a stage further on in the work instruction they have to click through 50 slides to get there etc. What I would like to do is have an index button on the screen that if clicked opens up a swiper grid. When a selection is made on the grid the action will transition back to the main swiper and slide the user to that slide in the thumb gallery.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- Page Title -->
    <title>Swiper Gallery</title>

    <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

    <!-- Custom styleSheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../template/swiper/css/styleHorizontal.css"

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/nordsec-sOGWRys5cb5_9PTV/stylesheet?id=giBGf1Ht_VvBBJ-t">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #000" class="swiper gallery">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/001.svg" loading="lazy"></object>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/002.svg" loading="lazy"></object>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/003.svg" loading="lazy"></object>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/004.svg" loading="lazy"></object>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/005.svg" loading="lazy"></object>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/007.svg" loading="lazy"></object>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/008.svg" loading="lazy"></object>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/009.svg" loading="lazy"></object>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/010.svg" loading="lazy"></object>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <!--<div class="index-button"></div>-->

    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>

    <div class="index-button"
        <button style="background: url(../../template/resources/Index-Black.svg); background-size: cover" onclick="window.location.href='SwiperGrid.html'"></button>
    </div>

    <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper gallery-thumbs">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/001.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/002.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/003.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/004.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/005.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/006.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/007.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/008.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/009.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/010.svg" loading="lazy"></></div>
 
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-progress-bar"></div>

    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../template/swiper/js/scriptHorizontal.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #808080;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

    .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: fill;
    }

.gallery {
    height: 85%;
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery-thumbs {
    height: 15%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
        width: 12.5%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: .5;
    }

        .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide:hover {
            opacity: .8;
        }

    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-active {
        opacity: 1;
        height: 100%;
        border: solid 3px;
        border-color: #007aff;
    }

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/*Common Navigation Button Properties*/
.swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next, .index-button, .logo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    width: 5vw;
    height: auto;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
    left: 2vw;
    content: url('../../../template/resources/Prev.svg');
}

.swiper-button-next {
    right: 2vw;
    content: url('../../../template/resources/Next.svg');
}

.index-button, .logo {
    top: 5vh;
}

.index-button {
    left: 2vw;
    width: 5vw;
    content: url('../../../template/resources/Index-Black.svg');
}

    .index-button:hover {
        content: url('../../../template/resources/Index-Orange.svg');
    }

.logo {
    right: 2vw;
    width: 10vw;
    content: url('../../../template/resources/Black.svg');
}

/*Button Default Opacity*/
.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev, .index-button, .logo {
    opacity: .7;
}

    /*Button Hover Opacity*/
    .swiper-button-prev:hover, .swiper-button-next:hover, .index-button:hover, .logo:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    /*swiper-button-prev:hover {
        content: url('../../../template/resources/Prev-Hover.svg');
    }

    .swiper-button-next:hover {
        content: url('../../../template/resources/Next-Hover.svg');
    }
}*/
    .logo:hover {
        content: url('../../../template/resources/Orange.svg');
    }

.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**JS - Thumb Gallery**

```
    slidesPerView: 1,
    freeMode: false,
    loop: false,
    speed: 700,
    effect: 'fade',
    // Enable keyboard navigation
    keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    // Progress bar
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        type: "progressbar"
    },
    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    keyboard: { enabled: true },
    lazy: true,
    virtual: true,
    watchSlidesProgress: true,
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    slidesPerGroupAuto: false,
});

let gallery_thumbs = new Swiper(".gallery-thumbs", {
    slidesPerView: "auto",
    lazy: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    loop: false,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    keyboard: { enabled: true },
});

gallery_thumbs.on('click', function () {
    const { clickedIndex } = this;
    gallery_thumbs.slideTo(clickedIndex);
    gallery_top.slideTo(clickedIndex);
    console.log('slide click', clickedIndex);
});

gallery_top.controller.control = gallery_thumbs;
gallery_thumbs.controller.control = gallery_top;

gallery_thumbs.slideTo(0);

const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
const div = document.getElementById('myDiv');

// define the function to change the HTML content
function changeContent() {
    div.innerHTML = '<object type="image/svg+xml" class="swiper-slide" data="images/8.svg"></object>'
        ;
}

// add event listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', changeContent);
```

**JS - Grid that I need help integrating into on JS file for navigation**

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 5,
    grid: {
        rows: 5,
        fill: 'row',
    },
    loop: false,
    spaceBetween: 20,
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
    },
    keyboard: { enabled: true },
    lazy: true,
    watchSlidesProgress: true,

});
```

I have tried creating a javascript button for the index to point to another html file containing the grid but feel like this it is a lot more work to create manual links for each grid image to point back to a specific slide in the starting html file.